# Help identifying parts for a novice

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Thanks for all of the help yesterday.  I am so thankful for this community since I am a novice.  I took a look through the Sterilite tub of LEGO again today and pulled some more creations that I thought would be worth a try posting here.  For what it is worth, I appear to have parts from the following sets:  Lego City Ambulance Helicopter; T. Rex Transport; Republic Fighter Tank; Yodi's Jedi Starfighter; The Phantom; Hogwort's Whimping Willow; Minecraft The Waterfall Base; Jakku Quadjumper; Tie Striker; Jokerland; Piranha Attack; Hulk v. Red Hulk; Simpson's House; The Penguin Arctic Roller; Airport Cargo Plane; Nexo Knights 70320; The Batmobile; The Riddler Riddle Racer and City Ferry.  I doubt I have any complete sets at this point though.  Does anyone recognize parts of any sets listed above or otherwise here, and which set?  Thanks so much!

1. [image: A Bag #2]
2. [image: A Bag #3]
3. [image: A Bag #3 with a torso]
4. [image: Bed]
5. [image: A creation that looks like a face in my imagination]
6. [image: Potentially part of Minecraft set(s)]
7. [image: Mini vehicles probably from separate sets]
8. [image: A box-like structure in my imagination]
9. [image: A vehicle part in my imagination]

Answer (score 5):

first picture

based on

- [BRICK 2X8](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6037398)
- 4x4 plate
- 4x10 plate

Is [21119: The Dungeon](https://brickset.com/sets/21119-1/The-Dungeon)

[image]

Second picture
Based on

- [6167798: Plate Round 4X4 with Ø16mm hole](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6167798)
- projectile

is [75239: Hoth Generator Attack](https://brickset.com/sets/75239-1/Hoth-Generator-Attack)
[image]

Third picture

Based on

- [LATTICE TOWER 2X2X10 W/CROSS](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6186292)
- Different red part

is [75894: 1967 Mini Cooper S Rally and 2018 MINI John Cooper Works Buggy](https://brickset.com/sets/75894-1/1967-Mini-Cooper-S-Rally-and-2018-MINI-John-Cooper-Works-Buggy)

[image]

Fourth Picture of the bed is from the Simpsons house

Fifth picture is [21140: The Chicken Coop](https://brickset.com/sets/21140-1/The-Chicken-Coop)

[image]

Sixth picture some minecraft set, probably hard to pinpoint which set

Seventh picture

[76070: Mighty Micros: Wonder Woman vs. Doomsday](https://brickset.com/sets/76070-1/Mighty-Micros-Wonder-Woman-vs-Doomsday) and [76064: Mighty Micros: Spider-Man vs. Green Goblin](https://brickset.com/sets/76064-1/Mighty-Micros-Spider-Man-vs-Green-Goblin)
[image]
[image]

Last picture
[75129: Wookiee Gunship Microfighter](https://brickset.com/sets/75129-1/Wookiee-Gunship-Microfighter)

[image]

Eighth picture no idea, looks like own creation of someone